# An issue with inserting blob data into SQL tables

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to create a code piece that inserts an object I've created to store data in a very specific way into an SQL table as a blob type, and it keeps giving me an ' sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.' error. 
Has any of you encountered something similar before? Do you have any ideas how to deal with it?

```
        conn = sqlite3.connect('my_database.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        params = (self.question_id, i) #i is the object in question
        c.execute('''
                INSERT INTO '''+self.current_test_name+''' VALUES (?, ?)
                ''',params)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, this would be a more appropriate execute statement as it is way cleaner:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO "+self.current_test_name+" VALUES (?, ?)", (self.question_id, i))
```

You are also missing the table you are inserting into (or the columns if `self.current_test_name` is the table name.)
Also, Is the column in the database setup to handle the data type for the provided input for `self.question_id` and `i`? (Not expecting `TEXT` when you provided `INT`?)

Example of a working script to insert into a table that has 2 columns named `test` and `test2`:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('my_database.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(test INT, test2 INT)")
conn.commit()

for i in range(10):
    params = (i, i)  # i is the object in question
    c.execute("INSERT INTO test (test, test2) VALUES (?, ?)", params)
    conn.commit()
conn.close()
```